# 404 Not Found error when using VersionResoureResolver

Tags: java, spring, versioning

MvcConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc

public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
  @Bean
  public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter(){
    return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
       .addResourceLocations("/js")
       .setCachePeriod(60 * 60 * 24 365)
       .resourceChain(false)
       .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
  }
}
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>resourceFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springramework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>resourceUrlFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/egovframework/springmvc/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>action></servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xdo</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.geo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="viewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="1"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" id="jsonView" p:contentType="application/json;charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Hello, I have set my Spring web project above for auto-versioning that static resources are auto-built without cache reload passively when the content is changed.

But, it doesn't work as usual.
Firstly, the URL with MD5 hash is generated greatly if I use it in JSP like this <c:url value='/js/common.js'/>.(Thanks to ResourceUrlEncodingFilter).
(e.g. common-a3d8d7780349a12d739799e9aa7d2623.js)

But, it doesn't open up well when trying to connect to changed hash coded URL through chrome web browser.
it indicates that 404 Not Found error.

Any suggestions out there?
I am so confused. because I thought it works like a charm as I setup correctly viewing this reference (https://www.baeldung.com/cachable-static-assets-with-spring-mvc)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I doubt this even works. There is no `DispatcherServlet` in there so nothing Spring related is going to be loaded or effective.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for reply! I added DispatcherServlet from the source.  Everything works fine without requesting MD5 hash coded static resources.

Comment: Still it wouldn't work as the `DispatcherServlet` is only mapped to 3 URL endings. Why is the default servlet even in there. Ditch that and bind the `DispatcherServlet to `/` instead of just 3 urls. If the request never reaches the servlet it will do nothing.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks again! I ditched it and added '/' to the DispatcherServlet area.
But, it doesn't work also. 
The same thing  happens. The new URL(MD5 hash coded) is generated good(common-a3d8d7780349a12d739799e9aa7d2623.js) in the source. But, when I request it on the web browser, 404 Not Found popped up again.

The old static resource url (common.js) works though.

Comment: I also suspect you need to add the `ResourceUrlProviderExposingInterceptor` as an interceptor, so it is accessible by the `ResourceUrlEncodingFilter`. That being said you are linking to a resource that is for Spring Boot (which does a lot of auto configuration) whilst you are using plain Spring, for which you can better read the regular Spring Documentation (not the Spring Boot documentation).

Comment: Upon further inspection that shouldn't be needed as it is added automatically.

Comment: Is the JSP accessed through the DispatcherServlet or is directly accessible?

Comment: @M.Deinum Wow! It works like a charm as you show me the answer. Thank you M. Deinum. You made my day. Have a nice day!